# how can I translate 翳红?

Tags: translation, meaning

翳 means 'to cover'(?), does it mean veiled red in the compound word 翳红? I couldn't find any reference in dictionaries
thank you, rosa

Comment: Where's this word from?

Comment: 红翳:  https://books.google.ca/books?id=qkAlBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT9&lpg=PT9&dq=%E7%BF%B3%E7%B4%85&source=bl&ots=jFpoJg3Hhb&sig=FfK7qlY6Fc_vYr4-uStU3fdH16c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP4aOIxIXTAhWK5oMKHRJkCeYQ6AEINzAI#v=onepage&q=%E7%BF%B3%E7%B4%85&f=false 'veiled red' (of eyes)

Answer (score 7):

> 楊牧 《十二月十日辭清水灣》
>
> 我探首看崖下潮來潮去
>   讓記憶擱淺在那裏。正午
>   窗子裏空氣虛構一種寧靜
>   花瓣無懈可擊，紛紛拋落針織
>   刺繡上，暗微的香氣洴澼浮沉
>   湧進我多風的心裏
>
> 光影在石礁一帶遊戲。遙遠
>   水鳥各自東西，隨我的意志
>   翻飛，有些在夢的邊緣失落
>   有些自動回歸。山勢略顯憂愁
>   傾斜若時間之餘韻
>   太陽在翳紅與蒼黃間忐忑滑行
>
> By the cliffs, I overlook a tide that comes and goes
>   and leave my memory stranded there. At noon
>   behind the window the air fabricates tranquillity
>   the petals are impeccable, their delicate
>   fragrance scattered over the stitching
>   floating, rushing down to my goustrous heart
>
> Light and shadow play around the rocks. Further out
>   seagulls break from each other, fluttering
>   by my grit some are lost at the edge of dreams
>   though others return. The ridge seems to dishearten
>   it lies aslant like the rests in a temporal cadence
>   with care the sun slides from crimson to straw
>
> [利文祺 和 Colin Bramwell 合譯](https://www.wenchili.com/blank-8)

翳紅 crimson

蒼黃 straw

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest "dull red", or "red with a low saturation".

because, 翳 has a meaning of "to shade"

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=翳](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%BF%B3)

imaging something that's underneath a tree on a sunny day, that it's color would be less bright, less clear; compare to others in direct sunlight.

Answer (score 0):

翳红
1.一种颜色，类似暗红色；
2.指一种具有特殊暗红色斑点或花纹的玉石，产自缅甸或罗马尼亚（不确定）；
3.指一种常见眼病。
4....
...(maybe more meaning!)
Please translate based on the meaning on context.

Comment: Where did you find this definition?

Comment: The definition of this kind of commonly-used words are too basic to enter professional Chinese dictionary. You can only find the meaning of both characters but not the word. To get the meaning, you should check Chinese literature for reference of how the word was used. Also some authorized newspapers and magazines have the power of distinguish between right and wrong usage of a word. The last two meanings are found frequently in contemporary newspapers if you focus on certain parts. The first meaning is the basic one determined by both characters' meaning and by grammar of composition, easily.

Comment: So you wrote this definition yourself?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I can't find any interpretation about “翳红”.I think it's not a word.